# How can one know if a set is compact?

Tags: general-topology

How can one know if a set is compact? From the definition, a set is compact if for any open cover, there exist a finite subcover. However, it is not possible to list out all the open covers to a set. So is there any way one can know if it is a compact set? In the case $R^n$ it is easy as one only needs to check the set is closed bounded but what about other metric space or other spaces?

Comment: Do you have an example of a space that u want to show that it is compact

Comment: @Amr Is there any general way to do it?

Comment: I guess there isnt

Comment: Or a generL way might be checking the definition itself. But I don't know if there exists an equivalent definition that is somehow much easier to check

Comment: This relationship is 'iff'. The true power of defining it this way - and there has historically been debate about the best way of defining compact - is to use it if compact, then open cover... Using it the other way round can be tricky. I suggest you take amr up on what probably was an offer to show you how to use it to show compactness. This takes a bit time to sink in, but you'll soon find it natural.

Comment: @Amr What about a set of all continuous function in the interval $[0,1]$ with supremum norm metric?

Comment: @Mathematics: That is certainly not compact, since the sets $\{f\mid \sup |f| < n\}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ cover the space but don't have a finite subcover.

Comment: @Mathematics: See [here](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~speicher/Chapter10.pdf) for examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An equivalent condition in the case of metric spaces is sequential compactness: Every sequence in the space has a convergent subsequence.

There exist a number of other characterizations, but they are usually not that easy to verify (such as being complete and totally bounded).

Often, one can use basic properties of compactness to show a given space is compact. For example, a closed subset of a compact set is compact and the forward image of a compact set under a continous function is compact.

There are many results for showing that some spaces are compact. These include the [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem), the [Banach–Alaoglu theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem), and a number of other results. These results are important precisely because it is in general often nontrivial to show that some space is compact.